# Show Array ID in column using DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using DataTables on a page, with the source data being in a javascript array.

The table structure is very simple; the aoColumns section is:

```
"aoColumns" : [
        { "sTitle" : "Who"},
        { "sTitle" : "What" },
        { "sTitle" : "Status" }
    ]
```

When I display the table, I'd like to have the first column show the index of the row from the source array.

So, if aaData contained:

```
["John", "Do something", "Waiting"],
["Jane", "More things", "Done"],
["Zed", "Stay awesome", "Ongoing]
```

Then, the table would actually display:

```
ID | Who  | What         | Status**
0  | John | Do Something | Waiting
1  | Jane | ....
2  | Zed  | ....
```

Bonus appreciation for how to have the ID shown in the table actually be the array index + 1 (so, John's row would start with 1, Jane's with 2 and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function to construct your table:

```
  otable.fnClearTable();
  $.each(datasource, function(key, value) {
    //Want that Bonus:-)
    var id = key + 1;
    otable.dataTable().fnAddData([
      id,
      value[0],
      value[1],
      value[2],
    ]);
  });
```

[Working Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/36aySAsaanpGbfes8HcM?p=preview)

Comment: Very cool thank you. And the bonus is there :) Thank you. 
Out of interest, can it be done using the more standard table creation code like shown http://jsfiddle.net/Mb9He/ ?

Comment: Best way to do this would be to add an index to your array before applying dataTables. This can easily be done in a loop. Heres a plunker that SHOWS an index while rendering a row. It does not add the actual data, so index is not sortable. Hope this helps anyhow. http://plnkr.co/edit/1WJlNf1zqTIXj72ff7G7?p=preview